# How do I destroy the parent and all children associated through the parent when one child is destroyed in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm not sure how to setup the associations for these models. The associations I have are

```
1) Client - belongs_to :person
2) User - belongs_to :person
3) Person - has_one of everything above
```

I have the appropriate `"dependent: :destroy"` with the `belongs_to`. The issue is, Client and User may or may not be associated with the same Person record. If they are and a Client is destroyed, I want the User to be destroyed also. Similarly, with the same association, If the User is destroyed, I want the client to be destroyed as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. In Client

```
belongs_to :person, dependent: :destroy
```

In User

```
belongs_to :person, dependent: :destroy
```

In Person

```
has_one :client, dependent: :delete
has_one :user, dependent: :delete
```